# Matplotlib cannot correctly process numbers greater than 19 in a diagram?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When I try to visualize data in Matplotlib in a bar chart, and the numbers have more than 19 characters, then the chart is not visualized correctly.

I wanted to create a bar chart that visualizes the following table ([from this website](https://cube20.org/)):

| Distance (x axis) | Count of Positions (y axis) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 18 |
| 2 | 243 |
| 3 | 3,240 |
| 4 | 43,239 |
| 5 | 574,908 |
| 6 | 7,618,438 |
| 7 | 100,803,036 |
| 8 | 1,332,343,288 |
| 9 | 17,596,479,795 |
| 10 | 232,248,063,316 |
| 11 | 3,063,288,809,012 |
| 12 | 40,374,425,656,248 |
| 13 | 531,653,418,284,628 |
| 14 | 6,989,320,578,825,358 |
| 15 | 91,365,146,187,124,313 |
| 16 | 1,100,000,000,000,000,000 |
| 17 | 12,000,000,000,000,000,000 |
| 18 | 29,000,000,000,000,000,000 |
| 19 | 1,500,000,000,000,000,000 |
| 20 | 490,000,000 |

So, I tried following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/[name]/Downloads/gods number.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
X = list(df.iloc[:, 0])
Y = list(df.iloc[:, 1])


plt.bar(X, Y)
```

With following csv file:

```
0, 1
1, 18
2, 243
3, 324
4, 43239
5, 574908
6, 7618438
7, 100803036
8, 1332343288
9, 17596479795
10, 232248063316
11, 3063288809012
12, 40374425656248
13, 531653418284628
14, 6989320578825358
15, 91365146187124313
16, 1100000000000000000
17, 12000000000000000000
18, 29000000000000000000
19, 1500000000000000000
20, 490000000
```

It did this:

[image: 1]

Next I edited the CSV file an shortend every number that is longer than 19 characters, so the file looked like this:

```
0, 1
1, 18
2, 243
3, 324
4, 43239
5, 574908
6, 7618438
7, 100803036
8, 1332343288
9, 17596479795
10, 232248063316
11, 3063288809012
12, 40374425656248
13, 531653418284628
14, 6989320578825358
15, 91365146187124313
16, 1100000000000000000
17, 1200000000000000000
18, 2900000000000000000
19, 1500000000000000000
20, 490000000
```

It works!

[image]

So, how to get around this 19 character limit?

Comment: You probably need to tell `pd.read_csv` that that column should be represented by floats, not by numpy integers (or maybe just change the first entry to `0, 1.0`). Did you look at the dataframe? The problem is unrelated to matplotlib. Apart from that, using a logscale for the y axis could enable to see more bars than only the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
(
    pd.read_html("https://cube20.org/")[2]
        .replace(r"about\s|,", "", regex=True)
        .astype({"Count of Positions": float})
        .plot.bar(x="Distance", y="Count of Positions", legend=False)
)
```

Output :

[image]

Or if you need a logscale (as suggested by @[*JohanC*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc)), add `.set_yscale("log")` as a last chain.

[image]